# Settar o height de uma band dinamicamente no JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Eu estou fazendo um projeto pra facilitar a criação de relatórios com `DynamicJasper` e cheguei em uma parte onde eu tenho que posicionar um elemento que está na `Band PageHeader` manualmente, settando a posição X e Y, e isso é feito depois da geração do relatório pelo `DynamicJasper`, o problema é que depois que eu posiciono o elemento a altura da `Band PageHeader` continua igual mesmo com o elemento em outra posição e sobra um espaço vazio entre a `Band PageHeader` e as outras `Bands` abaixo.
Então queria saber se é possível settar o `height` da `Band PageHeader` dinamicamente pra que não fique este espaço vazio?

Código final onde faço o build do relatório do `DynamicJasper` e onde quero fazer isso:

```
final DynamicReport dynamicReport = this.fastReportBuilder.build();
dynamicReport.setAllowDetailSplit(true);

final JasperReport jasperReport = DynamicJasperHelper.generateJasperReport(dynamicReport, new ClassicLayoutManager(), null);

((JRDesignBand) jasperReport.getPageHeader()).setHeight(200); // <- Não funciona :S

final JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dados));

this.templateBuilder.setPageObjectsPosition(jasperPrint);
//... more code ...//
```

Answer (score 1):

Cara, eu uso assim:

```
JasperDesign jasperDesign = new JasperDesign();
jasperDesign.setPageHeight()
```